# Error while changing password

Tags: linux, passwords, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 normally, but I don't know why after I logout and login back to my daily use user (someone), it said that authentication doesn't work. I logged in the root account and try changing the password of someone but it said "BAD PASSWORD: The password contains less than 1 non-alphanumeric characters". I tried the passwd command on tty console and cockpit.

This is the screenshot:
[image]

anyone knows what the problem is? thanks for helping me.

Comment: It tells you that the password you want to use isn't complex enough? So pick a password das adheres to the password policy?

Comment: I don't think, when I logout and try re-login it said authentication doesn't work. I fixed it with a reboot but I'm still wondering about the issue.

Comment: If the error was that authentication doesn't work it's likely that the authenticaiton service did have an issue. My guess would be that you're not using a local user to actually log in?

Comment: Yes it is a local user. I logged in successfully then logout, but cannot login again.